# Code Folding for CSS in VSCode

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, editor, indentation, folding

I can't get code folding to work in the editor in Css. In both html and js I can fold code according to comments, which enables me to create neat groups. But in Css you can't fold comments. Does anyone know of a way to enable this or another nice tip for creating groups of code in a Css file? Here are some pictures.

Here you can see there is not minus button next to the Own Classes comment:

[image]

But here you can see the comments fold nicely in js, this enables me to create nice groups of code:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

See [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding) to read about **code folding** in VS Code:

> Since the 1.22 release, folding ranges can also be computed based on
>   syntax tokens of the editor's configured language. The following
>   languages already provide syntax aware folding:
>
> Markdown, HTML, CSS, LESS, SCSS and JSON
>
> CSS/Less/SCSS: `/*#region*/` and `/*#endregion*/`

[image]

So your code folding based on syntax should be activated by default for CSS. You can switch back to using indentation for CSS with the following setting:

```
"[css]": {
  "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"
},
```

Comment: There we go thank you! Adding your settings code into my settings solved the problem perfectly.  :)

Comment: Any ideas how to enable region folding for stylus? `"[stylus]": { "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation" },` didnt work :(

Comment: Just learned this now. Very helpful, thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

In the latest version of VS code you don't have to turn on specific rule inside Settings JSON. Just define an opening comment with the `#region` and when you want to close the group create another one with `#endregion`. Example:

```css
/* #region */
.class { 
  color: red
}
/* #endregion */
```

In case you want to name your regions (which is normally the case), you can define the label next to the first region comment like

```css
/* #region This is the group label */
.class { 
  color: red
}
/* #endregion */
```

Tested on Version: 1.67.2

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for vs code and webstorm:

```
//#region This is the group label

//#endregion
```