# VSCode Fold Ts Comments

Tags: visual-studio-code, folding

How do I fold indented .ts comments in vscode. I could have sworn I used to be able to do this but can't anymore. For example, here the folding is not there when I hover over the Imports comment side.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See the answer here: [Code Folding for CSS in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50791492/code-folding-for-css-in-vscode)

To enable indented-comment-folding add this to your settings:

```
"[css]": {
  "editor.foldingStrategy": "indentation"
},
```

`css` can be replaced with `scss` `typescript` `javascript` `html`...